# Mainboards ATX "PWR_OK" signal fried

Tags: power-supply, power, atx, motherboard

I've been struggling here trying to find out what exactly went wrong, but I just can't. 
I messed around with a power supply and decided to wire up my own with 3.3V, 5V, 12V and all other connections needed on a ATX connector. The computer did turn on, but since the keyboard and mice were on but not working, I thought it has something to to with the PWR_OK not connected.I then connected it to ground and the computer did made a click and reset itself, then while I was holding the wire, it clicked about 2 or 3 times more and that was it. It doesn't POST anymore. No beep, just fan spin.
Measuring the PWR_OK gives 4.97V, so it's being pulled high somehow, but a circuitry likely doesn't recognize it anymore.

I also searched on Google, but nothing... I think nobody does stupid stuff like that.

What could it be, which circuitry is responsible for that part?

I really want to get that motherboard back to work. It's not a expensive one, but it's that I don't have any anymore (now).

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Grounding the wire still makes the computer click. Putting 5V does nothing.

EDIT2: Maybe a photo helps:
[image: 20181028-080301.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

The ATX power supply specification specifies a sequence in which the power rails must come up in, along with minimum timing between them. If you did not obey these requirements, you may well have fried components on the motherboard.

Also, the PC BIOS is supposed to assert PWR_ON (triggered by the power button) before the PC generates any voltages, other than +5V stand-by. If you gave the mobo voltage before it requested it, you may also have burned something out.

I’d suggest, if you haven’t already, trying a standard ATX power supply. If that doesn’t work, the mobo is probably toast. Sorry.

Comment: I messed around some more yesterday and I finally released the magical smoke of it, so it's now officially dead, but thanks for answering.